# Запрос с помощью Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

Здравствуйте, есть одна база данных.

При выводе таблицы на HTML-страницу она выглядит так:

Заявитель|Возраст|Рост|Вес|Возраст|Рост|Вес

Заявка 1 |19     |190 |75 |19     |190 |75

Заявка 1 |19     |190 |75 |19     |190 |75

Заявка 1 |19     |190 |75 |19     |190 |75

Заявка 2 |21     |170 |67 |21     |170 |67

Заявка 2 |21     |170 |67 |21     |170 |67

Заявка 2 |21     |170 |67 |21     |170 |67

Мне нужно привести к такому виду

Заявитель|Возраст|Рост|Вес

Заявка 1 |19     |190 |75 |
Заявка 2 |21     |170 |67 |

Сама таблица из бд выглядит так, id заявки, поле, значение.

Вопрос, можно ли средствами ORM, создать запрос который будет все записи с одним  значением в (id заявки) преобразовывать в один объект, или это нужно делать на уровне HTML-кода?

Сейчас запрос выглядит так:

```
FieldsValues.objects.all()
```

Comment: По-моему тут надо решать не следствие, а причину. Нормально ли это, что в БД вообще оказались дубликаты?

Comment: Это не дубликаты, это структура БД. Например две записи из таблицы: 4(ID), 17(значение), 5(ид поля(например возраст). 4(ID), 179(значение), 7(ид поля(например рост).

Answer (score 1):

Помогло использование условного оператора if в шаблоне. Запрос к базе делал через id.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто убрать повторяющиеся данные, то можно воспользоваться [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

```
FieldsValues.objects.distinct()
```

Comment: Спасибо, но  в моём случае distinct не работает

Comment: Попробуйте явно задать сортировку и по какому полю удалять совпадения `FieldsValues.objects.order_by(field_name).distinct(field_name)`

Comment: при таком distinct, значение для следующей заявки берутся из первой

Comment: Возможно дело в сложных связях через ManyToMany